# Standard diagonal argument to extract a subsequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a sequence of function $\{u_m\}_m$ in $L^p(V)$ where $V$ is a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists a subsequence 
$\{u_{m_j}\}_j$ such that 
$$\limsup_{j,k\rightarrow\infty}||u_{m_j}-u_{m_k}||_{L^q(V)}\leq\delta$$

How can I conclude that there exists a subsequence $\{{u_{m_l}}\}_l$ satisfying
$$\limsup_{l,k\rightarrow\infty}||u_{m_l}-u_{m_k}||_{L^q(V)}=0$$

Comment: For the sake of clarity, consider the subsequence we're constructing by $\{ v_n\}$. For each $n$, consider $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$. Choose $v_n$ from the resulting subsequence.

Comment: Ok I had the same idea. But in the book is written to use a diagonal argument and this is not diagonal so I was thinking that I was wrong

Comment: I think it is, in the sense that if you were to write out all the elements of all the sequences you use, one below the other, the new sequence would be the diagonal of that infinite square.